# Twilio Call, use custom endpoint for xml

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Using this code, i am able to receive the call and listen to the contents coming from the voice.xml.

```
client.calls
  .create({
    url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
    from: '+16173973230',
    to: '+13392153860'
  })
  .then(call => console.log(call.sid))
```

I'm trying to use my own generated twiml but when i change to

```
url: 'http://myserver.com/twilio/auto-message.xml',
```

which replies exactly the same way:

```
twilioRouter.get('/auto-message.xml', (req, res) => {
  res.type('text/xml')
  res.send(`<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">Thanks for calling the E T Phone Home Service.</Say>
</Response>`)
})
```

I get a giant (error) log in the console and on the phone call i hear "We are sorry, an application error has occurred. Goodbye"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Twilio uses a POST by default. You can tell Twilio to use a GET where you configure the webhook for your phone number.

Comment: please add it as an answer so i can mark it as correc

Answer (score 0):

Twilio uses a POST by default. You can tell Twilio to use a GET where you configure the webhook for your phone number.